# NettyConnectorProvider (jersey-netty-connector) doesn't send query parameters in the Get Request

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, netty, connector

I am trying to send an HTTP request with query parameters using **Jersey Client** and setting **NettyConnectorProvider** (org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-netty-connector:2.25.1) as a provider to the config (org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig) by the method connectorProvider().

Looking in the source code of NettyConectorProvider, it uses the method **requestUri.getRawPath())** during the creation of **DefaultFullHttpRequest**, but this method return the path without the query parameters.

```
nettyRequest = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                                          HttpMethod.valueOf(jerseyRequest.getMethod()),
                                          requestUri.getRawPath());
```

How can I send query parameters in a GET request using NettyConnectorProvider or is there a knowledge issue related to query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket in the GitHub fixing this problem.
It is possible to track the solution by the links below:

[NettyConnectorProvider (jersey-netty-connector) doesn't send query parameters in the Get Request](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4369)
[Query parameters were not included in netty URI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/4393)